# How to reduce steepness of logistic curve?

Tags: mathematical-modeling

I am simulating an assay with the following equation:
$$y =  xd(1 - \frac{x}{k})$$
where $d$ is the duplication time and $k$ is the asimptote. However, the simaluted curve (in red) is too steep compared to the actual data (green and blue):
[image]
Is there a way to reduce the 'steepness' of the curve? I tried with a lower duplication value but it only translates the data, not the curve. Same thing with k.

Thank you.

Comment: Is it given that $y =  xd(1 - \frac{x}{k})$ or are you free to assume the form of the relationship between $x$ and $y$? Even if the relationship is known/given, the value of $d$ and $k$ should be calculated from your data. Fortunately, in this case, that should not be difficult. Please post your data if possible.

Comment: I am using d=2, k=$10^13$. But even if I use a lower d or k the steepness is the same. Perhaps there is another term to add to make the curve more similar to the actual ones?